# Setting max Length for Sentence in StanfordCoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to restrict the max length for a sentence in StanfordCoreNLP. For some reason it does not seem to honor this property. This flag is part of the LexicalizedParser. But I am using StanfordCoreNLP instance in my class. Wondering what is the right way to set this flag.

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.put("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner");
 properties.put("-maxLength", "100"); // does not work
 StanfordCoreNLP nap = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
```

Comment: Further digging into the source code I found praser.maxlen and pos.maxlen properties are being used in the Stanford Core NLP code. But it is not throwing the exception I was expecting when the sentence length is exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

At present, CoreNLP has no general maxLength flag. Individual Annotators may have one like `parse.maxlen`, but if the sentence is too long, that means simply skipping running that annotator.

Comment: Where can I find the information on how to set the maximum length for single parsers? I am currently having the problem that my machine runs OOM under the CoreNLP Server - it's not that the data set is so huge, it seems the server just eats up all the available memory over time and from the looks it could mean that the sentences are too long.