# getting error while splitting text into sentences using CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm doing text analysis on news articles related to financial markets. An example text from those news feeds

> "We would have to assess it more from the side of CBS to make sure
>   they weren't investing in a bad deal," Michael Cuggino, president and
>   portfolio manager at San Francisco-based Permanent Portfolio Family of
>   Funds, which owns voting shares of CBS and Viacom, told
>   Reuters.Salvatore Muoio, principal with New York-based S. Muoio & Co,
>   a major owner of Viacom voting shares, said a bidding process for
>   Viacom would realize the most value.Viacom could give companies such
>   as AMC and Discovery programing and scale to better negotiate for
>   higher fees from cable and satellite distributors, Muoio
>   said.Representatives for Verizon, Apple and Discovery declined to
>   comment."

I'm using Stanford CoreNLP library for analysis.

In the above text

```
Reuters.Salvatore
```

should be

```
Reuters. Salvatore
```

Due to this error, coreNLP parser is throwing sentence maxlen warning and sometimes NullPointerException because it is not able to correctly split text into sentences.

This type of error occurs randomly in some of the texts.
How can I get CoreNLP to work with these kind of text?

Comment: Is punctuation important in your data? Could you split or otherwise remove them periods?

Answer (score 0):

If skipping sentences that are too long is acceptable for your use case (so that at least it proceeds with the rest of the data), maybe this is what you need: [Setting max Length for Sentence in StanfordCoreNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159699/setting-max-length-for-sentence-in-stanfordcorenlp)

Comment: No, I can't afford to skip sentences. After splitting the text into sentences with corenlp, I'm using regex to split the sentences again. Though it's not perfect solution, but  it has reduced the error rate sufficiently.